# how are nullable types implemented under the hood in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

In our own Jon Skeet's [C# in depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/), he discusses the 3 ways to simulate a 'null' for value types:

- Magic value (e.g. earliest possible DateTime is taken to be 'null')
- Reference type wrapper
- boolean flag

It is mentioned that nullable types use the third method. How exactly do nullable types work under the hood?

Comment: shameless plug: I wrote a blog post about how it works a little while ago: http://softwareblog.alcedo.com/post/2010/02/16/Nullable3cT3e-vs-null.aspx

Comment: @FredrikMörk The link is no longer available...

Comment: @M.Mimpen Now it's available again. That blog sort of crashed on me a while ago, but I have republished elsewhere, but have redirects for the original url's.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ultimately, they are just a generic struct with a bool flag - except with special boxing rules. Because structs are (by default) initialized to zero, the bool defaults to false (no value):

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct {
    private readonly T value;
    private readonly bool hasValue;
    public Nullable(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        hasValue = true;
    }
    public T Value {
        get {
           if(!hasValue) throw some exception ;-p
           return value;
        }
    }
    public T GetValueOrDefault() { return value; }
    public bool HasValue {get {return hasValue;}}
    public static explicit operator T(Nullable<T> value) {
        return value.Value; }
    public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(T value) {
        return new Nullable<T>(value); }
}
```

Extra differences, though:

- special boxing rules (you can't normally do this)
- special C# rules for comparing to null etc
- "lifted" operators in C# (and in .NET via `EqualityComparer<T>`, `Comparer<T>` etc)
- special rules on generic type constraints (to prevent `Nullable<Nullable<T>>`)

Comment: How is the boxing handled? Can I implement my own boxing rules for my own structs?

Comment: It is handled by special rules in the CLI. No, you *cannot* do this yourself. Likewise the "lifted" operators aren't something you can do yourself.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the behaviour of operators is governed by the language - C# and VB have different rules on this for various operators.

Comment: I just ran across a difference: you can give a `T?` method parameter a default value of `T`, but if you implement your own kind of nullable and try to do the same, you get a compile error. (E.g., "A value of type 'bool' cannot be used as a default parameter as there are no standard conversions to type 'MyNullable<bool>'".) Does that fall under one of your bullets?

Answer (score 4):

`Nullable<T>` works by providing two fields:

```
private bool hasValue;
internal T value;
```

The properties work from those.  If you set it to `null`, hasValue is set to false.

Comment: But it is not simply possible because `T` as well as `Nullable<T>` are structuress and structure cannot be easily set to `null`.