# How Does .Net Allow Nullables To Be Set To Null

Tags: c#, .net, null, clr, nullable

The `Nullable<T>` type is defined as a `struct`.  In .Net, you can't assign `null` to a `struct` because `structs` are value types that cannot be represented with `null` (with the exception of `Nullable<T>`).

```
int i = null; // won't compile - we all know this
int? i = null; // will compile, and I'm glad it does, and it should compile, but why?
```

How did `Nullable<T>` become an exception to the rule "You can't assign `null` to a value type?"  The decompiled code for `Nullable<T>` offers no insights as of to how this happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how are nullable types implemented under the hood in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503811/how-are-nullable-types-implemented-under-the-hood-in-net)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How did `Nullable<T>` become an exception to the rule "You can't assign null to a value type?"

By changing the language, basically. The `null` literal went from being "a null reference" to "the null value of the relevant type".

At execution time, "the null value" for a nullable value type is a value where the `HasValue` property returns `false`. So this:

```
int? x = null;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int? x = new int?();
```

It's worth separating the *framework* parts of `Nullable<T>` from the language and CLR aspects. In fact, the CLR itself doesn't need to know much about nullable value types - as far as I'm aware, the only important aspect is that the null value of a nullable value type is boxed to a null reference, and you can unbox a null reference to the null value of any nullable value type. Even that was only introduced just before .NET 2.0's final release.

The language support mostly consists of:

- Syntactic sugar in the form of `?` so `int?` is equivalent to `Nullable<int>`
- [Lifted operators](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/06/27/what-exactly-does-lifted-mean.aspx)
- The changed meaning of `null`
- The null-coalescing operator (`??`) - which isn't restricted to nullable value types

Comment: @Dan: If you want lots more detail, I dedicate a whole chapter to nullable value types in C# in Depth :)

Comment: @JonSkeet So what would it take to make `int i = null;` equivalent to `int i = new int();`?

Comment: I suppose runtime will just set `HasValue` property to false when we set `int i = null;` Am I right @Jon

Comment: @Dan: It would take a new C# compiler, basically :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: It doesn't need to set it to false; that's the default value for the type, which is important for arrays etc. Basically there's a `bool` field inside the type.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yep, I already knew about it. What if when `i` already has value now we over write it with `null`? will that set the boolean to false or create new nullable?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: It will completely replace the old value with the new value (a pair of `hasValue=null`, `value=0`). This is perfectly normal struct behaviour.

Comment: @Jon am really confused at the moment on eric's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3049653/2530848). Eric says nullabletypes aren't atomic(I agree) other thread can read a partially value. I know this cannot happen for reference types if we create `new` object since constructor gets executed first and then only it gets assigned to variable. but how this is possible for value types? will it be stored in a variable first and then initialized?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: No, the point is that the amount of data being written may be more than the processor guarantees can be atomically transferred - just like writes of `double` and `long` aren't guaranteed to be atomic.

Comment: So does that means another thread can read partially written value? being a immutable struct can other thread read its value partially written? Sorry if am taking up your time

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yes. Again, this is the same as with normal value types. It's just a matter of not being able to guarantee that a large "chunk" of data writing will be performed atomically.

Comment: Thanks Jon, one more thing to confirm will this happen with immutable reference types. I believe no.? am I right? just to confirm with you

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: No, because then you'd only be copying a *reference* from place to place, and the reference writes are guaranteed to be atomic.